# Getting error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Tags: c++, arguments, evaluate

I'm getting this error

Error    5    error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xrefwrap    431    1

after trying to do this

```
typedef std::function<int(int, int)> op;


op someOperator = std::plus<int>();
op someOtherOperator = std::minus<int>();
```

so I can call a function like

```
UpdateValues(int X, int Y, op One, op Two)
{
      //eventually doing something like
      One(X, someOtherInt);
      Two(Y, someOtherInt);
}
```

What is going on?

Here is a link to my files if you need them https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn2akcyb9f448e6/Checkers.rar?dl=0

Comment: Compiles and runs on [ideone](http://ideone.com/0MHO4x). Try to post a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: So out of all of those files you posted, we're supposed to hunt around for this code that doesn't compile?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer vsoftco, in the end there were three separate things that kept generating that error:

I was passing an op object in place of a bool parameter 
I was passing an op* object in place of an op parameter
I was passing an op object in place of an op* paramater